# Having CSS issue: can't place text right of select box

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Why is the word "user" appearing under the select box? I want it to be on the right side of select box. What am I missing?

> http://jsfiddle.net/njh85/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
          <select id="users" name="userName">
            <option value="#">
              Select one...
            </option>
            <option value='1'>
              User1
            </option>
            <option value='2'>
              User2
            </option>
            <option value='3'>
              User3
            </option>
            <option value='4'>
              Demo
            </option>
          </select>
</div>
<div id="user">Here is a sample sentence :)</div>
```

​
**CSS:**

```
/*Users Combobox*/
.ui-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 36px;
}
.ui-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    /* adjust styles for IE 6/7 */
    *height: 1.7em;
    *top: 0.1em;
}
.ui-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
#user {
 position: relative;
 top: -27px;
 left: 270px;   
}
```

​
**FIDDLE:**

> http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/njh85/10/

All you have to do is move the text left and up from where it normally is which is possible by using: `position: relative`. Also the text is outside the `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Move it inside the div right after your select box and add some right margin to your `.ui-combobox`

http://jsfiddle.net/njh85/9/

Comment: No. Can't. Word "user" is just sample. There is sentence after selectbox. Suggest something outside of this div

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="ui-widget">
          <select id="users" name="userName">
            <option value="#">
              Select one...
            </option>
            <option value='1'>
              User1
            </option>
            <option value='2'>
              User2
            </option>
            <option value='3'>
              User3
            </option>
            <option value='4'>
              Demo
            </option>
          </select>
       <div class="words"> user</div></div>
```

Use the word "user" inside the div tags

```
  .words{
    float:right;
    color:#808080;
    font-family:Sans,ubuntu;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-right:100px;

}
```

Comment: No. Can't. Word "user" is just sample. There are more than 1 word

Comment: So use that words within another div elements .and give css style for that .

Comment: In order to make the float work it needs to appear before the selectbox in the markup.